# searching for words from a text file in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I've been developing a discord bot for my server to delete slurs, and its going well, but i want to know how I would use this line of code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "slur" in message.content:
        print("slur deleted")
        await message.channel.send("No cussing!")
        await client.process_commands(message)
        await message.delete()
```

read from a list of words in a .txt file instead of that one word?

Comment: you can create a list of words then use for i in list if i==message.content

Comment: You shouldn't put your `process_commands()` inside. Put it outside of your `if`.

Answer (score 0):

so make one file , lets assume file name `words.txt` and then we will open file and put all words in each line.And remember all words should be in lower cases in the file
and then use this code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("words.txt","r") as f:
        words = f.readlines()
    if words in message.content.lower():
        print("slur deleted")
        await message.channel.send("No cussing!")
        await message.delete()
    await client.process_commands(message)
```